# JSON Array get JsonObject always returns empty

Tags: java, json

I have been running into an issue lately with org.json. I have made a json array with the following text:

> ```
>     [{"name":"Stk.","unitNumber":1,"self":"https://link.com/units/1","products":"https://link.com/units/1/products"},{"name":"timer","unitNumber":2,"self":"https://link.com/units/2","products":"https://link.com/units/2/products"},{"name":"Stk.","unitNumber":3,"self":"https://link.com/units/3","products":"https://link.com/units/3/products"},{"name":"Kg","unitNumber":4,"self":"https://link.com/units/4","products":"https://link.com/units/4/products"},{"name":"Kg","unitNumber":5,"self":"https://link.com/units/5","products":"https://link.com/units/5/products"},{"name":"Km","unitNumber":6,"self":"https://link.com/units/6","products":"https://link.com/units/6/products"},{"name":"Liter","unitNumber":7,"self":"https://link.com/units/7","products":"https://link.com/units/7/products"},{"name":"Meter","unitNumber":8,"self":"https://link.com/units/8","products":"https://link.com/units/8/products"},{"name":"M2","unitNumber":9,"self":"https://link.com/units/9","products":"https://link.com/units/9/products"},{"name":"MM","unitNumber":10,"self":"https://link.com/units/10","products":"https://link.com/units/10/products"},{"name":"Meter","unitNumber":11,"self":"https://link.com/units/11","products":"https://link.com/units/11/products"},{"name":"Par","unitNumber":13,"self":"https://link.com/units/13","products":"https://link.com/units/13/products"},{"name":"Stk.","unitNumber":14,"self":"https://link.com/units/14","products":"https://link.com/units/14/products"},{"name":"Stk.","unitNumber":15,"self":"https://link.com/units/15","products":"https://link.com/units/15/products"},{"name":"Sæt","unitNumber":16,"self":"https://link.com/units/16","products":"https://link.com/units/16/products"},{"name":"Sæt","unitNumber":17,"self":"https://link.com/units/17","products":"https://link.com/units/17/products"},{"name":"\u200e","unitNumber":19,"self":"https://link.com/units/19","products":"https://link.com/units/19/products"},{"name":"Stk.","unitNumber":20,"self":"https://link.com/units/20","products":"https://link.com/units/20/products"},{"name":"Stk.","unitNumber":21,"self":"https://link.com/units/21","products":"https://link.com/units/21/products"},{"name":"L","unitNumber":22,"self":"https://link.com/units/22","products":"https://link.com/units/22/products"}]
> ```

Now, I run the following code

```
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));
                System.out.print("\n"+jsonObject1.toString());
            }
```

And I get

> {"empty":false}

Every time.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add a minimal reproducible example. From the given information, it's not possible to say what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code and surround it with try catch for JSONException

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    System.out.print("\n"+jsonObject1.toString());
}
```